# CentOS 7 + PHP7 — php not rendering in browser

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, centos7, php7

I have a clean install of apache/httpd and php7.1.0 running on CentOS 7.

When I execute from the command line:

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59
```

and

```
php -v
```

I get the expected response

```
PHP 7.1.22 (cli) (built: Sep 12 2018 07:22:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EyS5.png)

But when I try to hit my phpinfo.php page, all I get is...  literally outputted to the screen - can someone tell me what I'm missing, did I forget to enable a mod?

Comment: Did you install and activate mod_php?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing mod_php or enabling it if you have already installed it.
I have not work on centos 7 recently so dont know how to do that,simple google search should be ok.

Comment: tried mod_php enabling no use, it should be the same.

Comment: @amith, I did Google search after that also can't find the resolution so posted here, if I get in google search why should I post here